# Get ringtones from WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, ringtone

i save ringtones using SaveRingtoneTask:

```
    private SaveRingtoneTask saveRingtoneChooser;

    public void SaveRingtone(Uri source)
    {
        saveRingtoneChooser.Source = source;
        saveRingtoneChooser.DisplayName = AppResources.SaveRingtoneTaskDisplayName;
        saveRingtoneChooser.Show();
    }
```

but i don't how i can get ringtones in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Your app cannot access existing ringtones on the device, you can only save a custom ringtone to the device just like you have showed.